# Visualize php variable values and call stack in IDE(Zend Studio)

Tags: php

I want to see the call stack and object values and methods in case of an exception in the IDE(Zend Studio or Eclipse PDT). Just this morning I saw a guy paste an image. I can't find it now, but it had all the values of variables and objects.

I've heard xdebug is used for this purpose, but can't figure out how to use it. 
I am using XAMPP and Zend Studio on localhost. I want to see these things the way Visual Studio shows them.
Can someone help me get started with this?

Comment: I use WAMP. The latest WAMP comes with XDEBUB installed on PHP 5.3v. Just make sure you tick the Remote Debug in the PHP settings menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

those call stack can only be seen in debug mode perspective. you may need to enter few breakpoints in your code so that you can get clear picture whats going on. Zend studio has inbuilt debugger so you dont need XDebug to start with. But yes you can always turn off Zend debugger to use XDebug but both of them do pretty much the same thing with few differences

Comment: How do I enable this. I suppose, you need to configure some things?

Comment: try reading this tutorial, http://files.zend.com/help/Beta/Zend_Studio_8_0/working_with_the_debugger.htm it explains a lot

Comment: or if you want to use XDebug then read this great startup tutorial http://devzone.zend.com/1147/debugging-php-applications-with-xdebug/

Comment: did I hit the right nail? or do you have any more questions regarding this. Cheers bro!

Comment: THanks! I haven;t tried this out, but I will as soon as I get sometime'